# In kubernetes, is there a way to know the percentage of requests went to different PODs with load balancing?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

In Kubernetes, is there a way to know the percentage of requests went to different  PODs with load balancing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

You write the query to derive the **%** of requests to specific POD out of **total** **requests**.

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/

Answer (score 0):

This is a common practise for monitoring pods and can be achieved using dashboards and monitoring apis. One good option is using ELK stack which comes with kibana dashboard having functionality to apply different filters eg. pod name

For this, all the logs need to be brought under common place for search capabilities to function efficiently.

Other common option can you can check is logtail or wavefront graphs.